# Petapoco - invoke stored procedure with several output parameters

Tags: c#, petapoco

This code works fine:

```
var unitOfWorkProvider = new PetaPocoUnitOfWorkProvider();

using (var uow = unitOfWorkProvider.GetUnitOfWork("SomeConnectionString"))
{
    var errorNumber = new SqlParameter("@ErrorNumber", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
    var errorSeverity = new SqlParameter("@ErrorSeverity", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
    var errorState = new SqlParameter("@ErrorState", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
    var errorProcedure = new SqlParameter("@ErrorProcedure", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output, Size = 128 };
    var errorLine = new SqlParameter("@ErrorLine", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
    var errorMessage = new SqlParameter("@ErrorMessage", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output, Size = 4000 };

    var sqlScript = Sql.Builder.Append(";EXEC @0 " +
                   " @@Uid = @1," +
                   " @@ErrorNumber = @2 OUTPUT," +
                   " @@ErrorSeverity = @3 OUTPUT," +
                   " @@ErrorState = @4 OUTPUT," +
                   " @@ErrorProcedure = @5 OUTPUT," +
                   " @@ErrorLine = @6 OUTPUT," +
                   " @@ErrorMessage = @7 OUTPUT",
    "[Schema].[USP_BlaDiBla]",
    new Guid("1E454A42-CC41-4FA1-BE91-1F7689986A23").ToString(),
    errorNumber,
    errorSeverity,
    errorState,
    errorProcedure,
    errorLine,
    errorMessage
   );

   var result = UnitOfWork.Current.FirstOrDefault<SomeDto>(sqlScript);
}
```

if the underlying stored procedure does not return any errors / output parameters.

Unfortunately, I get this exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

if the underlying stored procedure throws an exception. I traced the generated SQL and it works fine. Hence there must be an issue with this code related to Petapoco.

PS:

Here is a simpler version:

```
var database = new Database("SpacesConnectionString");
var returnValue = new SqlParameter("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
var sqlScript = Sql.Builder.Append(";EXEC @0 " +
                   " @@ReturnValue = @1,",
    "[dbo].[USP_Test] "
    , returnValue
    );

database.EnableAutoSelect = false;
var result = database.Query<dynamic>(sqlScript).ToList();
```

sproc code:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
            FROM    sys.objects
            WHERE   type = N'P'
                    AND name = N'USP_Test' )
    DROP PROCEDURE USP_Test
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: 
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_Test
    @ReturnValue INT OUTPUT
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SELECT @ReturnValue = 1
    END
```

PPS:

Looks like [this link](http://taylonr.com/getting-a-return-value-from-a-stored-procedure-in-petapoco/) helps. This is working code for the above simplified example:

```
var database = new Database("SpacesConnectionString");

var sql = new Sql().Append("DECLARE @@ReturnValue INT")
    .Append("EXECUTE [dbo].[USP_Test] @@ReturnValue OUTPUT")
    .Append("SELECT @@ReturnValue");

var ret = database.ExecuteScalar<int>(sql);
```

Comment: Where exactly do you get that error?

Comment: var result = UnitOfWork.Current.FirstOrDefault<SomeDto>(sqlScript);

Comment: By running independently the generated SP, do you get any results?

Comment: yes as I said the traced sql works.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try something like this:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
public class PetaPocoUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly Transaction _petaTransaction;
    private readonly Database _db;

    public PetaPocoUnitOfWork(string connectionString)
    {
        _db = new Database(connectionString);
        _petaTransaction = new Transaction(_db);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _petaTransaction.Dispose();
    }

    public Database Db
    {
        get { return _db; }
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        _petaTransaction.Complete();
    }
}

public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    void Commit();
    Database Db { get; }
}

public interface IUnitOfWorkProvider
{
    IUnitOfWork GetUnitOfWork(string connectionString);
}

public class PetaPocoUnitOfWorkProvider : IUnitOfWorkProvider
{
    public IUnitOfWork GetUnitOfWork(string connectionString)
    {
        return new PetaPocoUnitOfWork(connectionString);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var unitOfWorkProvider = new PetaPocoUnitOfWorkProvider();

        using (var uow = unitOfWorkProvider.GetUnitOfWork(""))
        {
            var errorNumber = new SqlParameter("@ErrorNumber", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
            var errorSeverity = new SqlParameter("@ErrorSeverity", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
            var errorState = new SqlParameter("@ErrorState", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
            var errorProcedure = new SqlParameter("@ErrorProcedure", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output, Size = 128 };
            var errorLine = new SqlParameter("@ErrorLine", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
            var errorMessage = new SqlParameter("@ErrorMessage", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output, Size = 4000 };

            var sqlScript = Sql.Builder.Append(";EXEC @0 " +
                           " @@Uid = @1," +
                           " @@ErrorNumber = @2 OUTPUT," +
                           " @@ErrorSeverity = @3 OUTPUT," +
                           " @@ErrorState = @4 OUTPUT," +
                           " @@ErrorProcedure = @5 OUTPUT," +
                           " @@ErrorLine = @6 OUTPUT," +
                           " @@ErrorMessage = @7 OUTPUT",
            "[Schema].[USP_BlaDiBla]",
            new Guid("1E454A42-CC41-4FA1-BE91-1F7689986A23").ToString(),
            errorNumber,
            errorSeverity,
            errorState,
            errorProcedure,
            errorLine,
            errorMessage
           );

            var result = uow.Db.SingleOrDefault<object>(sqlScript);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems to emit the same sql to the database. However, i have narrows done the method it falls over. Its PetaPoco's Database class method string FormatCommand. The passed  object[] args are null after the @@Uid parameter.

Comment: This seems to indicate why petapoco does not work (it looks as if was developed without full sproc support): http://taylonr.com/getting-a-return-value-from-a-stored-procedure-in-petapoco/